# Is MSAL integration mandatory for MS Intune SDK integration in an Android app?

Tags: android, intune

In MS Intune official guide for SDK integration for Android, they have supported case of no MSAL or ADAL integrated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-android#1-app-does-not-integrate-msal-or-adal

Now, in inquiry mail from MS Intune team about our answers for MS Intune Questionnaire for registration, they asked question as "What are your authentication scenarios?"

Can anyone confirm that we can integrate MS Intune SDK in Android app without integrating MSAL?

Answer (score 0):

@vatsalengg
You can use default enrollment. However, but please note this is only intended to be used for apps that are only used by Intune users. If you'd like to ship your app to the Play Store for a broader audience, you must use MSAL and the MAMEnrollmentManager APIs.
please check issue here for more clarity https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/Taskr-Sample-Intune-Android-App/issues/21